# How or where do I change permissions in DNN for the toolbarbuttonextsioncontrol?

Tags: c#, user-controls, dotnetnuke

On the site I am working with in DNN, there is a

```
<div id="dnnModuleDigitalDocumentsMainToolbar">                
                <dnnext:ToolBarButtonExtensionControl Module="DigitalDocuments" runat="server" ID="MainToolBar" Group="Main" IsHost="<%# IsHostPortal %>" />    
            </div>
```

This menubar has 'Action' buttons for Upload Files, Create New Folder and Upload Bulk.  However, when not logged in as HOST, I am not able to click on those buttons.

I tried adding permissions to a user for both the page and the module, but neither of them worked.  I am not sure what this extension control is looking at when building the buttons to determine permissions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information (DNN version, which module are you talking about)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am on DNN 7.4 I believe, and the module is called DigitalDocuments.  I am not sure if its a custom module or prepackaged from DNN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are "Action Buttons" that appear only in Edit Mode, then they are available only to users who are logged in and have administrative privileges to the module.  In other words, they are meant to be used by Administrators and not by other site users.

---

You can verify your DNN version by looking at the Host, Host Settings page when logged in as a super usere.

DigitalDocuments is not a module provided by DNN.  So, it's either a third party module or a custom one.  If you go to the Host, Extensions page you can click the Edit (pencil) icon to potentially learn more about the module, including who created it.